# About timing precision of sdf file when simulation in ncsim

Tags: simulation, sdf

I find my  ncsim can only simualte the sdf file in precision of 10ps （round to 10ps）
For exampe，This is a simple BUF sdf information:

```
(CELL
  (CELLTYPE "BUFCLKHD30X")
  (INSTANCE U10)
  (DELAY
    (ABSOLUTE
    (IOPATH A Z (0.263:0.266:0.266) (0.257:0.259:0.259))
    )
  )
)
```

When I observe the timing sequence in simvision window, I found the simulator will round it to 270p when Z transfering from 0 to 1 because of the changing of A.

In my sdf file the Timescale (unit) is 1 ns. And in my testbench is 1ns/1ps. And according the tools documentation from cadence, the default timing precision of sdf elaberating/compiling is 1fs. I think that means we do not need to set any precision relating compiler option (like sdf_precision 1ps) in ma case. (BTW, I have tried such complier option, but help nothing).

How can I watch/oberseve a delay of 266ps or say precision in 1ps from my simulation window？ Mnay thanks.!
My ncsim version is IES 2012, I thnik it was "latest" enough.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding these parameters to your ncelab call:

```
-timescale 1ns/1fs -vhdl_time_precision 1fs -override_precision
```

I had the same issue a few weeks ago and used this to solve it. It took me some time before I found out the importance of the last parameter.
Good luck!